# Antd table rendered n... tables during creation new records instead of 1

Tags: reactjs, antd

Got the problem during the creation of new records and the rendering of the table, for some reason, the record is added to the new table instead of filling in the previous one. How can I fix this behavior? I tried to pass the key as an identifier: key: id, and to the Table a rowKey parameter also - but everything was unsuccessful.

[image]

Code - BookItem component:

```
    export const BookItem = ({id, title, author }) => {
        const queryClient = useQueryClient()
        const { mutateAsync, isLoading } = useMutation(removeBook)
    
        const remove = async () => {
            await mutateAsync(id)
            queryClient.invalidateQueries('books')
        }
     
    
           const columns = [
                    {
                        title: 'Title',
                        dataIndex: 'title',
                        key: id,
                        render: (data) => <Link component={StyledLink} to={/update-book/${id}} mr="auto">{data}</Link>
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Author',
                        dataIndex: 'author',
                        key: id
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Action',
                        render: () => <Button backgroundColor="#cc1c28" onClick={remove}>{ isLoading ? <Loader type="ThreeDots" color="#fff" height={10} /> : "Remove" }</Button>
                    }
                ];
                const data = [
                    {
                        key: id,
                        title: title,
                        author: author,
                    }
                ];
                return (
                    <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} size="middle" />
            );
};
```

BookList component:

```
export const BooksList = () => {
    const { data, error, isLoading, isError } = useQuery("books", getAllBooks);

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Flex py="5" justifyContent="center">
                    <Loader type="ThreeDots" color="#cccccc" height={30} />
                </Flex>
            </Container>
        );
    }

    if (isError) {
        return <span>Error: {error.message}</span>;
    }
    return (
        <Container>
                {data.map(({ author, title, id }) => (
                    <BookItem author={author} title={title} key={id} id={id} />
                    ))}


        </Container>
    );

};
```

Comment: You need to show more code. This code working fine

Comment: @Viet Did you mean another components that linked to the render ?

Comment: Components are using this table . May be it call 3 times

Comment: @Viet Added to the edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `Table` without `map` like this:

```
<Container>
  <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} size="middle" />
</Container>
```

Comment: But it is placed inside another component, how does it know which columns and data it should access? I'm mean that I have a BookItem where I process the antd table, and BookList that iterates through all items inside the BookItem component - and return the data.

Comment: Just move `columns` to `BookList `

Comment: It turned out to render the table thank you, but what about the handlers that are hung on the buttons and the router?